# How to embedded Instagram feed into my website

Tags: html, embed, instagram-api, feed

I am trying to integrate the Instagram feed of the client to the website sidebar. My website stack is Bootstrap, Vanilla JS, Jquery, and Laravel.

I googled and did some research. I can't find a direct way to integrate the feeds.

I went through third-party apps like Snapwidget. It's pretty good but the problem with an app like Snapwidget is that when I click on the feed displayed on the sidebar widget provided by it, it redirects to its own site's page which contains my uploaded images.

I want my feed to look pretty in the sidebar and when users click on my picture they should be redirected to that Instagram account page not a third-party website with my Instagram feed or that feed on Instagram itself.

Meanwhile, I also found other apps that provided the solution to it. They perfectly provide me ways to integrate feed as if provided by the Facebook API but at first, they demand to login with the credential. I can't ask for the username and password of the client's Instagram handle anyway.

Comment: is it a wordpress website or some static website?

Comment: thanks for reply this is website on laravel .. this is dynamic website

Comment: no problem, did you went through this? https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/

Comment: yes but this only teach to embeed specified post not feeds .

Comment: currently it seems like they only provide for post embed. i think you have to use a third party tool to achieve this. or use an iframe which is not accurate much

Comment: https://www.pixlee.com/social-feed this is a free third party tool

Comment: i havenot used this but tried my hand with other .  problem with third party tool is that when i click on the my images in my feed they redirect me to their website

Comment: i have posted another link in the answer with different free tools which provide instagram feed. But not sure with the redirect problem you mentioned, but i think you can change the redirection from the link your getting

Comment: I have added as an answer :) please do check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169132/discussion-between-pravin-poudel-and-lakindu-gunasekara).

Comment: Facebook removed the support for the Instagram profile posts. Here's the link for release notes: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/

Answer (score 18):

Currently Instagram supports for only post embed is seems. There is no direct implementation to instagram feed embed.
https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/

But there are third party tools which provide Instagram feed to be embed to your website.
Try free tools such as 
https://www.pixlee.com/social-feed to embed to your website.

You can try the following free tools in the article.
http://www.developerdrive.com/2017/09/how-to-embed-an-instagram-feed/

If the page redirects to their website, you can do a small hack in the provided URL. Try to change it to your Instagram account from the `a href link`

Comment: thanks but problem with third party is that i have login in instagram in their site and i cant do that with my client instagram .... assking credential to login in another site ...

Comment: Pixlee doesn't seem to let us do any customization. Like how many posts to show, post click behaviour. And their lightbox isn't responsive

Other than that it's pretty decent!